# Block loading behaviour in Drupal 8 in a performance sense through the visibility settings

Tags: performance, 8, blocks

The following scenario:
- i have for example a standard block region through a pages of a site: "highlights"
- for the frontpage i have an additional region: "highlights_frontpage"
- i put a block into "highlights_frontpage"
- i have to put into the visibility textarea: ""

If i remember correctly for D7, otherwise the block is loaded everywhere even though he is only shown on the frontpage.

Has Drupal 8 the same behaviour in loading blocks?
My page has for each main menu page an own region, but it would be a little bit ugly for the editor if he has to place the block via the administration in one region and also has to set the visibility ...

thanks

Comment: Interesting question. Can you test it yourself? A dpm() call in the block cobtent builder should inform you whether the function was run or not. Make sure you disable block cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block is loaded (otherwise we could not check if he should be shown or not), but we do not call build() unless the block is visible and the user has access.

I'm pretty sure that was already the case in Drupal 7, it is only Drupal 6 AFAIK where it was building the blocks and then checking visiblity.